# Repeat Emmet commands in vim with dot operator

Tags: vimrc, repeated-commands, plugin-emmet-vim

Is there a way i can repeat an emmet command in vim. Below is the sample text file

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

So i use emmet to wrap the the first line inside a `div` and then wanted to repeat the same on the second line. But when i press `.` it kind of deletes the second line and file looks like this

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

I know i can do this stuff with macros, but in my view macros is an over kill for just this thing. So is there any way i can repeat this with `.`. I tried `repeat.vim` plugin as well but it didn't work.

Comment: It looks like emmet does not support this. It has also already been raised on the issue tracker: https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/309